# SDL_Surface in QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, sdl

I want to use a `SDL_Surface` inside a Qt window.
I created a `SDL_Surface` using `SDL_CreateRGBSurface()`.
I know how to display a `QPixmap` in Qt window.
Now I only need to convert my `SDL_Surface` into `QPixmap`.
Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet worked on this particular problem, but my guess is, that you have to load the data from the `SDL_Surface` into the `QPixmap` with the according function. You could try it with [loadFromData](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpixmap.html#loadFromData). Of course, you have to declare the correct pixel format. This information can be retrieved from the surface.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the [SDL FAQ](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/FAQ_GUI) entry titled "Manually copy from non-window SDL_Surface to the GUI toolkit".